# silent command net stop

Tags: cmd, command

I need to stop a service that has dependencies.

Annoyingly it asks the user to press yes or no. The trouble is that I don't want it to ask. I want it to automatically do it.
for example

```
net stop msmq
```

but i cant see any possibilities.

```
NET
    [ ACCOUNTS | COMPUTER | CONFIG | CONTINUE | FILE | GROUP | HELP |
      HELPMSG | LOCALGROUP | PAUSE | SESSION | SHARE | START |
      STATISTICS | STOP | TIME | USE | USER | VIEW ]
```

Comment: Why is this off-topic ? The question asks whether the given command line api provides an option to run the command with a specific desired result ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the answer.
I tried to use this command:

```
net stop msmq /y
```